# WEBrick wont create a new web server on a fresh Application (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, web, webrick

This is what happens when I try and start a new web server with WEBrick.

I've been playing around with Ruby on Rails for a few days now but have been having a lot of trouble installing it on Windows. Now that I am here I'm not sure what is going wrong.

```
C:\Websites\Project_one>rails s
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configur
ation.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::A
pplication::Configuration:0x00000003ad7980> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Websites/Project_one/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Applica
tion>'
        from C:/Websites/Project_one/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Projec
tOne>'
        from C:/Websites/Project_one/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)
>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The first thing going wrong is the fact your are using Windowd for Rails development. This is not a good ideia, I may tell you.

Comment: About the error... It seems, at first sight, that ActiveRecord is not loaded for some reason.

Comment: You're telling me... hahaha I've had nothing but troubles so far! Do you know how I can move passed this?

Comment: Now, that's a great idea, Brad! LOL

Comment: When you set your Ubuntu box up, don't install Ruby using the .deb package. Use rvm.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida While [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) can make getting a development environment up very pleasant and painless, [Windows 10 is gaining the ability to run Ubuntu binaries internally with a robust shell](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-and-canonical-partner-to-bring-ubuntu-to-windows-10/) which will make Windows significantly more capable here. Today you can develop in Windows, it's just full of pitfalls because it's a second class citizen, lacking most of the POSIX shell features and system tools nearly every other OS takes for granted.

Comment: @tadman do you know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like line 24 of `config/application.rb` has an issue. Are you sure what you're configuring there is by the book?

Comment: @tadman I've been following a tutorial on lynda.com that was highly recommended and I've done everything right so far I've gone through it and triple checked so I'm really not sure what is wrong

Comment: @BradWice If you can amend your question with an edit to show what configuration you've done on the line that's causing the error. That would help clarify.

Comment: @tadman I'm really new to this so I apologize for not exactly knowing what you mean >.< Basically I have followed the steps all the way through, bundle install works fine and it says I have webrick but I get the following errors that I posted in the question above.

Comment: @tadman C:\Websites\Project_one>bundle show config
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pkg-config-1.1.7

Comment: No need to apologize for not knowing the answer, that's why you're asking a question after all. I'm asking about line 24 of `config/application.rb` specifically. What is it? When you get a stack trace error like this the first thing you need to do is look at the spot where execution stopped.

Comment: @tadman Ah I understand, here it is: config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

Comment: That should be fine, but it's possible ActiveRecord is somehow not loaded in your application and that doesn't exist. What example are you working from?

Comment: Ruby on Rails Essentials 4 from Lynda.com @tadman